# URL with multiple ending parentheses produces broken links in markdown preview

Tags: support, bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

I tried to create a link to `https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=rktl#(idx._(gentag._305._(lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl)))` using Markdown in this way:

```
[example](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=rktl#(idx._(gentag._305._(lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl))))
```

But in the preview that appears when editing questions, this is rendered:

```
example))
```

... which is incorrect. It appears fine once the edit is saved, but causes an annoyance when editing.

You can observe this bug by editing this question. Take note of how this link is rendered in the preview:

[example](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=rktl#(idx._(gentag._305._(lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl))))

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the edit preview]

Comment: If you replace the last ending parenthesis in the URL with %29, does it work?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog No. Replacing the last ending parenthesis with %29 does not work.

Comment: How about if you replace *all* the right parentheses in the URL with %29?

Comment: Seems fixed, least on meta, when I pick the edit option on this post

Answer (score 3):

In case, if parentheses `(` and `)` are coming inside the URL, you can escape it by `\(` and `\)`.

```
[example](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=rktl#\(idx._\(gentag._305._\(lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl\)\)\))
```

render as:

[example](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=rktl#(idx._(gentag._305._(lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl))))

Comment: If the actual output is going to be the same regardless of whether or not parentheses are escaped, what is the point of escaping parentheses?

Comment: @Flux With out the backslashes, the actual output is displaying the [broken link in the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9oVq.png). If you are clicked on the link in the preview, it won't navigate to the expected section.

Comment: Yes, broken, but only in the preview and not in the actual output displayed after saving the preview. Preview does not match actual output after saving. That's the bug. I don't see why I should always add backslashes just to get the preview working correctly...

Comment: To summarize, the bug here is that the preview mismatches the output.

Answer (score 1):

The use of %2F (coding) in the URL hints that the remainder of the URL is also encoded, which isn't true; that causes mode switching and resets the parentheses count.

For example:

[Test of link](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=rktl#(idx._(gentag._305._(lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl)))) in MarkDown rendering. - Use your URL and  Button above.

[Test of link](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=rktl#(idx._(gentag._305._(lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl)))) using brackets and parentheses. - Duplicate your example.

[Test of link](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=rktl#(idx._(gentag._305._(lib._scribblings/reference/reference..scrbl)))) using brackets, parentheses, and backslashes. **- Use** ***no*** **URL encoding** and .

[Test of link](https://docs.racket-lang.org%2Freference%2FFilesystem.html%3Fq%3Drktl%23%28idx._%28gentag._305._%28lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl%29%29%29) using ***fully*** encoded URL (but keeping the protocol selection unencoded).

Using your example (exactly) but using a **fully unencoded URL** `https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=rktl#(idx._(gentag._305._(lib._scribblings/reference/reference..scrbl)))` (instead of a partially encoded URL, with %2F's in it) **OR** a **fully encoded URL, excluding the protocol** `https://docs.racket-lang.org%2Freference%2FFilesystem.html%3Fq%3Drktl%23%28idx._%28gentag._305._%28lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl%29%29%29`, instead of mixing the input, **produces the correct decoding** in the renderer.

[URLDecoder.com](https://www.urldecoder.org/) explains:

> "... many URI schemes and protocols based on RFCs 1738 and 2396 presume that the data characters will be converted to bytes according to some unspecified character encoding before being represented in a URI by unreserved characters or percent-encoded bytes. If the scheme does not allow the URI to provide a hint as to what encoding was used, or if the encoding conflicts with the use of ASCII to percent-encode reserved and unreserved characters, then the URI cannot be reliably interpreted. Some schemes fail to account for encoding at all, and instead just suggest that data characters map directly to URI characters, which leaves it up to implementations to decide whether and how to percent-encode data characters that are in neither the reserved nor unreserved sets.

Comment: The fourth link is broken.

Comment: That is odd, it used to work. Currently it requires encoding of everything but the parentheses or the site 404's the URL. Here's the minimum that I could leave unencoded: [https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=rktl%23%28idx._%28gentag._305._%28lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl%29%29%29](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=rktl%23%28idx._%28gentag._305._%28lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl%29%29%29).