# Closing as duplicate produces a comment with broken markdown and link, if the question title is too long

Tags: bug, comments, design, russian-stackoverflow

On https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/, I tried to close a question as a duplicate of [Что делать при получении сообщения «Вопросы/ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5149/215103).

This generated following canned comment, which seems to have been truncated to fit the character limit.

> `Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делать при получении сообщения «Вопросы/ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5149/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%83%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%`

This rendered to:

> Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делать при получении сообщения «Вопросы/ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются»?]([Что делать при получении сообщения «Вопросы/ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5149/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%83%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%)

Notice the missing `)` at the end, which breaks the markdown. The link itself is also broken.

The bunch of `%` characters is an (incomplete) result of URL-encoding the cyrillic text in the link, which would decode to `https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5149/Что-делать-при-получении-сообщения-Вопросы-ответы-участника-с-данной-учётной-за`, if it wasn't truncated.

**I propose that the URLs in dupe comments should have question title stripped.** Like this:

> `Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делать при получении сообщения «Вопросы/ответы участника с данной учётной записью больше не принимаются»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5149)`

We could also add the user id at the end of the link (like in the links generated by pressing 'share'), but this doesn't seem important to me.

Comment: @bobble On one hand that seems to be the same issue. On the other, I'm fairly sure that if we close this, nobody will ever see both questions ever again. :/

Comment: [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without)

Comment: Related, and probably the underlying cause: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317128/282094

Comment: @Rob I don't think so. Normally dupe links do work on ru.SO, assuming they fit in the character limit.

Comment: Another good reason why links shouldn't count toward the comment length limit as was requested [multiple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137036/348196) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267293/348196).

Comment: It's just silly that the shortened version of the link isn't provided in the comment in these cases; that would prevent this from ever occurring, regardless of the title length/ language.